Entity Creation
I had a city called "Lavaresque" which is not known by the interpreter. The following command Interpreted["City"]["Lavaresque"] failed although this town exists. I would like to know how to create a new entity for this city in Mathematica. Ideally, this entity should be included in the Entity list related to "City".

The city/town/village does not appear in the Geonames open database of municipalities with a population of >1000.  Do you have the lat-long for the place? Is it a municipal division of a larger municipal area?

Similar question with no answers: Create Items that have same type/class as existing Wolfram Class.

What country? Perhaps Interpreter["City"]["Lavare"]

No it is not Lavare. Lavaresque is a small village in France located in the Aisne department. However my question was how can I create a new entity "City"
